# Launching gazebo server

Tags: ros, gazebo, world

[image: Rosanswers logo]

BH

I'm trying to launch a gazebo server with the help of gzserver but I get this error:

Error [RTShaderSystem.cc:409] Unable to find shader lib. Shader generating will fail.Error [Server.cc:285] Could not open file[worlds/empty.world]

When I go to the directory where empty.world xml file is placed I see it exists.
This is its content:

model://sun
model://ground_plane
<max_step_size>0.01</max_step_size><real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor><real_time_update_rate>100</real_time_update_rate>0 0 -9.8

Does someone have a clue what is wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207303/launching-gazebo-server/) by [Haz88](https://answers.ros.org/users/22113/haz88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-04-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered 'Error [Server.cc:285] Could not open file' when I tried launching gazebo with roslaunch gazebo_ros. I specified world_name:=<worldname.world> (from within the directory where the .world was located). When I added the full path to the file, the error went away.

---

Originally posted by [mattc_vec](https://answers.ros.org/users/22656/mattc_vec/) with karma: 50 on 2015-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriosMalonas](https://answers.ros.org/users/28158/dimitriosmalonas/) on 2016-10-05**:
Where do I add the full path?